How to resolve "Fatal Exception: java.lang.AbstractMethodError" in Firebase Installation Service Client
I am encountering a fatal exception error in my Android application, specifically related to the Firebase Installation Service Client. The error message reads:
Firebase exception:
Fatal Exception: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "androidx.appcompat.app.b androidx.appcompat.app.b.a0(int)" at com.google.firebase.installations.remote.FirebaseInstallationServiceClient.readGenerateAuthTokenResponse(FirebaseInstallationServiceClient.java:566) at com.google.firebase.installations.remote.FirebaseInstallationServiceClient.generateAuthToken(FirebaseInstallationServiceClient.java:416) at com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations.fetc
This error seems to be related to an abstract method within the androidx.appcompat.app package. I'm unsure how to diagnose and resolve this issue. Has anyone encountered a similar problem before? What steps can I take to troubleshoot and fix this error? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
I tried many time with log display and debug point but still I am not able to reproduce this issue.
In debug mode its working fine but in after release the new app I am getting this issue.
I have already using firebase progaurd rule also after google as below
-keep class com.firebase.** { ; }
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-keep class com.google.firebase.crashlytics.* { *; }
But overall still I am so confused why this error coming after app live on play store.
